# Is it possible to do hyperparameter optimization with a keras model on GCP

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform

Based on https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/hyperparameter-tuning-on-google-cloud-platform-is-now-faster-and-smarter

I ask if it also posisble to do  hyperparameter optimization with a keras model in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The same should work for [Keras model](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-keras#hyperparameter_tuning).

Some other references you might need.

[Hyperparameter tuning](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-hyperparameter-tuning)

[Configuring the job](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-jobs#configuring_the_job)

Comment: But I found hopefully the solution after spending hours searching!
Anyone whos is interested:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist.py#L102

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19295
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18247